# Trying to understand a simple function

Tags: statistics, machine-learning

I'm trying to make sense of a simple equation from Bingzhe Wu, Haodong Duan, Zhichao Liu, Guangyu Sun's paper [*SRPGAN: Perceptual Generative Adversarial Network for Single Image Super Resolution*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.05927)
[image: Formula from above paper]

What I don't understand is $\rho(x)=\sqrt{x^2 + \epsilon^2}$. How am I supposed to find $\epsilon$ (the error term I guess?) if $p$ only takes $x$ as input? Thanks

Comment: *Simple?* ${}{}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here, $\epsilon$ is a parameter and it is tuned. In the "Training Details" section (4.1), we see that

> We train our model from scratch with ADAM optimizer by setting $\beta_1 = 0.9, \beta_2 = 0.99,$ and $\epsilon = 10^{−8}$.

The Charbonnier penalty is a differentiable variant of the L1 norm. The parameter $ϵ$ determines how closely the penalty resembles the L1 penalty (while remaining differentiable).

Comment: But these parameters are for the optimizer, how is it related to the equation above?

Comment: I edited the answer to hopefully clear up the confusion.